# Exporting .p12 without password

Tags: macos, keychain, private-key

In order to use `Parse` for `push notification`, they ask that the `.p12` will NOT be protected with password.

When trying to export it from the keychain , the mac is force me to put the password, otherwise i can't export the file.

Is there a way to export it without the password ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. You can export `.p12` file with empty password. In other words without password.

Comment: how? Please mention here.

Answer (score -1):

Ok , i found the solution .

When you create a certificate to your mac, (.cer) you need to restart the computer after it, otherwise the login will not be connected to the new .cer (i had a previous one hence when i entered the administrator password ,he didn't accept it,because this login was under another .cer) .

Restarting the mac just solve the problem.